# KDE Main Toolbars Disappeared?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 and my desktop's main toolbars just disappeared.

The rest of the desktop runs just fine (Desktop icons). However, there is no system tray or the clock or the main menu that has system settings on it. (The entire bar is just gone)

Using `killall plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell` doesn't bring the bars back.

How can I get it back?

Comment: Have you logged out and logged back in? Have you rebooted? Have you tried adding back the panel by right-clicking on the desktop > Add Panel?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, I've tried logging back in, it didn't work. I reinstalled the kubuntu-desktop package and that brought it back for some reason.